# how to show login first alert and fade or disable the current page if not login and if login then don't show alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

suppose i have this post a job page

```html
<?php include_once "session.php" ;?>
<div id="wraper">

    <?php include_once 'header.php'; ?>
     <?php include_once 'navigationjp.php'; ?>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
<div >

<form class="form" action="" method="post" >
<div class="lbl"><label><h2>Job Title: </h2></label></div>
<input class="inpu" type="input" name="title" required placeholder="HR Manager" /><br>
<div class="lbl"><label><h2>Degree: </h2></label></div>
<input class="inpu" type="input" name="degree" placeholder="MBA (HR)"  /><br>
<div class="lbl"><label ><h2>Posts: </h2></label></div>
<input class="inpu" type="input" name="posts" placeholder="03" /><br>
<div class="lbl"><label><h2>Company: </h2></label></div>
<input class="inpu" type="input" name="company"  required="" placeholder="Diamond Pvt Ltd Company" /><br>
<div class="lbl"><label><h2>Contact No: </h2></label></div>
<input class="inpu" type="text" name="contact" id="contact" required placeholder="0423121212" /><br><br>
<div class="lbl"><label><h2> </h2></label></div>
<input class="inpu" type="submit" name="submit" value="Post job" />
</form>

</div>
         </div>
        <?php include_once 'sidebar.php'; ?>
    </div>
 <?php include_once 'footer.php'; ?>
    

</div>
```

and  i want that when someone click on form to write something it should check either user is signed in or not , if not signed in then i want to show an alert to user to login first if user is not signed in. how can i do it by using jquery or php ? can somebody tell me the example code please i don't know how to do it?

Comment: Do you have a login script? Do you have a way to check if the user is logged in? I would do this using ajax to check the user's logged in/out status, and use a jquery dialog (https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) to show the message if they are not logged in. There are plenty of examples of both here on SO.

Comment: i am finding since 2 hours no example found

Comment: Didn't answer the first 2 questions. Do you have a login script already? Do you have a way to check if the user is currently logged in?

Comment: yes i have login script and i have included session file as well but i want to check login only when user click on any input box on form

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have 2 ways to do it, first is check this when the user enter the page above with php, something like this:

```
<?php if (!$user) { >? 

<script>alert("Please log in first")</script>

<?php }?>
```

this will check the user right after he entered the page, you should provide us with more info about your login method and code so we can help you more specifically.

if you want to check if he is logged in after he already visited the page, you will need to use AJAX for that, php runs once after the page is loaded, so your way to talk with the php code after the page is loaded is with AJAX.

```
<script> 
  $("input.inpu").click(function() { //when the user clicked on the input
    //do your ajax here.
  });
</script>
```

you should read more about ajax here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/